# Friendly_id for fixtures (slugs)

Tags: testing, fixtures, friendly-id

I am using freindly_id in my application. I have setup a few fixtures in my application. I want to do integration testing on them. During the tests I need the friendly_id, but the DB records created from fixtures do not have the corresponding slugs in the Slug table.

Aren't the slugs automatically created from Fixture data? If not then what can be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to run the rake task that generates the slugs, but in the test environment.

On Windows

```
>set RAILS_ENV=test
>rake friendly_id:redo_slugs MODEL=xxx
```

Or Unix/Linux

```
>export RAILS_ENV=test
>rake friendly_id:redo_slugs MODEL=xxx
```

**Update**
The rake tasks have been removed, see comment to this answer or friendly_id README.

Comment: Note that the Rake tasks are gone in FriendlyId 4.  The author encourages you to write your own scripts/tasks for updating slugs on old records.  The easiest way is to run `MyModel.find_each(&:save)` from the console.  It'd be pretty simple to put that into a Rake task if needed.

Comment: I have a problem with this solution. If you have validation that ensures that your slug isn't null, then this won't work unless you take it out which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to add the `slug`s to the fixture data:

```
# test/fixtures/things.yml
apple:
  title: Apple
  restricted: hellyes
  slug: apple
```

```rb
# app/model/thing.rb
class Thing << ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```